# Android: Adding date formatting and sorting to an arrayList of items displayed in a listView

Tags: java, android, date, listview

I am trying to format a list of dates(on user entry) and display in chronological order in a list view.

I am currently able to display them in list view and enter them as an un-formatted date.

I am wanting to format them as follows: `DD/MM/YYYY`

This is the code i have for retrieving the date and the ID from the db and displaying it in the listView

**lessonNotesList class**:

```
    final int VALUE = extras.getInt("studentId");
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    final ArrayList id_list = mydb.getAllLessonIds(VALUE);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllLessonNotes(VALUE);
    //Collections.sort(array_list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    //Collections.sort(array_list);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
    //Adding the contacts to the list view.
    lessonNote = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewLesson);
    lessonNote.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //Setting an onClickListener to process the user's actions
    lessonNote.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //Prepare the data from the ListView item to be passed to new activity
            int id_To_Search =Integer.valueOf((String)id_list.get(arg2));
            //Log.d("Id is ^&*: ", String.valueOf(id_To_Search));
            //Create a new intent to open the DisplayContact activity
            Intent lessonList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.LessonNotes.class);
            lessonList.putExtra("studentId", VALUE);
            lessonList.putExtra("lessonId", id_To_Search);
            lessonList.putExtras(lessonList);
            startActivity(lessonList);
        }
    });
```

LessonNotesPage class (displays the lesson note information/allows for user entry)

```
    String dateLesson = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE));
        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
            rs.close();
        }
        lessonDate.setText(dateLesson);
        lessonDate.setFocusable(true); 
        lessonDate.setClickable(true);// allows user entry
```

How do I get the date formatted on user entry and how can i get it sorted in chronological order?

Comment: @BasilBourque - yes, actually, it does look very similar to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort your `ArrayList` of `String` dates named `array_list` try this:

```
Collections.sort(array_list, new Comparator<String>() {
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        try {
            return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to sort `ArrayList` of `Dates` is easier (primitive types does not  have `compareTo()`):

```
Collections.sort(array_list, new Comparator<Date>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add order by clause in your `sql` statement

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY datetime(dateColumn) DESC
```

and if you want to reorder when user changes date, use any sorting algorithm
and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```